# Unable to run a flink application on a cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I have a below example flink application which I am trying to run on a cluster.

```
public class ClusterConnect {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment
```

.createRemoteEnvironment("X.X.X.X", 6123, "");

```
    // get input data
    DataSet<String> text = env.fromElements("To be, or not to be,--that is the question:--",
            "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer", "The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune",
            "Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,");

    DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts = text
            .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void flatMap(String s, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> collector) throws Exception {
                    for (String word : s.split(" ")) {
                        collector.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(word, 1));
                    }
                }
            })
            .groupBy(0)
            .sum(1);

    // execute and print result
    counts.print();
    env.execute();
}
```

Cluster is setup with one jobmanager(free aws instance) and two tasks managers(free aws instances). While trying to run the above flink application on different AWS(which could reach the jobmanager, taskmanagers) hitting the following error.

Error from application:

```
WARN  [akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor] Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@172.31.29.190:6123] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
```

Logs from cluster job manager:

```
016-11-30 22:00:42,796 WARN  akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor                        - Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@172.31.6.190:33619] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [scala.Option; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2062608324514658839, local class serialVersionUID = -114498752079829388]
```

Comment: Figured out the problem! The flink application we were running has a version mismatch with the flink installed on the cluster. Thus the local class and stream class serialization error occurred. If anyone faces this problem, please make sure the flnk version in the pom file of your flink application matches the flink used in the cluster.

Comment: I have the same problem while I installed flink in my host and in cluster using the same flink package. Can you tell me what should I do?